2D smooth movement from scratch (javascript, pixelart)
My interest in game development led me to the idea of implementing the logic from scratch, without an engine.
Finally, I came to the point of optimizing the movement sequences of the background in an RPG 2D game. Basically, the implementation was not particularly complex due to the numerous help functions, but I am not completely satisfied.
I've only worked with canvas to a limited extent so far, which is why the code I've provided here can certainly be optimized. What interests me, however, is how the 8-direction system can be optimized.
Ultimately, it is not the user who is moved, but the background. This results in massive jerks due to the speed of movement and the specified number of pixels that have to be overcome.
Basically, I have a logic that allows me to normalize vectors, but the optimization guides I have noticed are not very helpful.
To make it clearer, I minimized the movement speed. I already played around with some delta values or tried to round some values but this ended very badly in some blurry pixel art.
Any idea in how to optimize this demo?


const game = document.querySelector('#game');
const context = game.getContext('2d');

const background = new Image();
background.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/82hX6qh.png';

const player = new Image();
player.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/LrL69By.png';

const backgroundHeight = 480;
const backgroundWidth = 840;
const playerHeight = 16;
const playerWidth = 12;

const initialGameWidth = 240;
const initialGameHeight = playerWidth * 10;

const cameraSpeed = 0.1;
const step = 1 / 60;

let x = backgroundWidth / 2; // Player Starting X
let y = backgroundHeight / 2; // Player Starting Y
let speed = 1;
let keymap = [];
let previousMs;
let cameraX = x;
let cameraY = y;

game.width = initialGameWidth;
game.height = initialGameHeight;

const handleScreens = () => {
    const scale = window.innerHeight / initialGameHeight;
    game.style.scale = scale;

    const gameHeight = Math.round(window.innerHeight / scale);
    const gameWidth = Math.round(window.innerWidth / scale);

    game.height = gameHeight % 2 ? gameHeight + 1 : gameHeight;
    game.width = gameWidth % 2 ? gameWidth + 1 : gameWidth;
};

handleScreens();
window.addEventListener('resize', () => handleScreens());

window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    let index = keymap.indexOf(event.key);

    if (index > -1) {
        keymap.splice(index, 1);
    }

    keymap.push(event.key);
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    let index = keymap.indexOf(event.key);

    if (index > -1) {
        keymap.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

const handleCamera = (currentValue, destinationValue) => {
    return currentValue * (1 - cameraSpeed) + destinationValue * cameraSpeed;
};

const handleWork = () => {
    let tempChange = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    [...keymap].forEach(direction => {
        switch (direction) {
            case 'ArrowRight':
                tempChange.x = 1;
                break;
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                tempChange.x = -1;
                break;
            case 'ArrowUp':
                tempChange.y = -1;
                break;
            case 'ArrowDown':
                tempChange.y = 1;
                break;
        }
    });

    let angle = Math.atan2(tempChange.y, tempChange.x);

    if (tempChange.x !== 0) {
        x += Math.cos(angle) * speed;
    }

    if (tempChange.y !== 0) {
        y += Math.sin(angle) * speed;
    }

    cameraX = handleCamera(cameraX, x);
    cameraY = handleCamera(cameraY, y);

    //context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
    context.save();
    context.translate(-cameraX + (game.width / 2) - (playerWidth / 2), -cameraY + (game.height / 2) - (playerHeight / 2));
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight);
    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, playerWidth, playerHeight, x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
    context.restore();
};

const main = (timestampMs) => {
    if (previousMs == undefined) {
        previousMs = timestampMs;
    }

    let delta = (timestampMs - previousMs) / 1000;

    while (delta >= step) {
        handleWork();
        delta -= step;
    }

    previousMs = timestampMs - delta * 1000;

    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

requestAnimationFrame(main);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#game {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
}
<canvas id="game"></canvas>




Are you looking for a kind of slide on keyup? Not sure exactly what smooth means as this (in terms of FPS) looks good to me.

@synnøve When dealing with bigger screens, like 1920x1080, the shifting is kinda more visible. The movement of the pixels are not clean. When looking at my commented code, there will be blur. With my current code, especially the diagonals, are very stairway. I've seen some implementation with the delta value added in movement for more "detail" but I dont know if this is the way to go here.

The canvas can only interpret integers, which is why it interpolates with decimal numbers. This interpolation ensures that the pixels are blurred, as an attempt is made to display an intermediate status of the two pixels.
One of the reasons for this is the scaling by CSS, which only scales up the element. The original pixels are still there, they are just perceived as larger.
However, as soon as you start scaling directly via canvas, not only are the pixels perceived as larger, but the interpolation is also improved, as it now has access to the intermediate pixels. This allows intermediate states to be displayed clearly.
This can be implemented as follows via canvas:
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
const scale = window.innerHeight / initialGameHeight;
context.scale(scale, scale);


If the speed is 7, the map will be displaced 7 pixels at a time, which can look a bit stuttery at a framerate of 24FPS. So the first thing you can do is set the FPS to 60 and the speed a bit lower.
const step = 1 / 60; 
const speed = 3;

It still stutters a bit, but this can also be caused by the browser/cpu doing other things which delays the requestAnimationframe calls.
You might also want to look at translate to move the map around. You can translate the whole canvas except the player character.
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(...); // movement
// draw the map here
ctx.restore();
// draw the player here



const game = document.querySelector('#game');
const context = game.getContext('2d');

const background = new Image();
background.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/Kjrpd2v.png';

const player = new Image();
player.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/PIT6zqs.png';

const initialGameWidth = 640;
const initialGameHeight = 360;

const step = 1 / 60;

let x = 3360 / 2;
let y = 1920 / 2;
let speed = 3;
let keymap = [];
let previousMs;

game.width = initialGameWidth;
game.height = initialGameHeight;

const handleScreens = () => {
    let scale = window.innerHeight / initialGameHeight;
    game.style.scale = scale < 1 ? 1 : scale;

    console.log(game.style.scale)

    game.height = window.innerHeight % 2 ? window.innerHeight - 1 : window.innerHeight;
    game.width = window.innerWidth % 2 ? window.innerWidth - 1 : window.innerWidth;
};

window.addEventListener('resize', () => handleScreens());
handleScreens();

window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    let index = keymap.indexOf(event.key);

    if (index > -1) {
        keymap.splice(index, 1);
    }

    keymap.push(event.key);
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {

    let index = keymap.indexOf(event.key);

    if (index > -1) {
        keymap.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

const handleWork = (delta) => {
    let tempChange = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    [...keymap].forEach(direction => {
        switch (direction) {
            case 'ArrowRight':
                tempChange.x = 1;
                break;
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                tempChange.x = -1;
                break;
            case 'ArrowUp':
                tempChange.y = -1;
                break;
            case 'ArrowDown':
                tempChange.y = 1;
                break;
        }
    });

    let angle = Math.atan2(tempChange.y, tempChange.x);

    if (tempChange.x !== 0) {
        x += Math.cos(angle) * speed;
    }

    if (tempChange.y !== 0) {
        y += Math.sin(angle) * speed;
    }

    // const mapX = Math.floor((game.width / 2) - 24 - x) + delta;
    // const mapY = Math.floor((game.height / 2) - 32 - y) + delta;

    const mapX = (game.width / 2) - 24 - x;
    const mapY = (game.height / 2) - 32 - y;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 3360, 1920, mapX, mapY, 3360, 1920);
    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, 48, 64, (game.width / 2) - 24, (game.height / 2) - 32, 48, 64);
};

const main = (timestampMs) => {
    if (previousMs == undefined) {
        previousMs = timestampMs;
    }

    let delta = (timestampMs - previousMs) / 1000;

    while (delta >= step) {
        handleWork(delta);
        delta -= step;
    }

    previousMs = timestampMs - delta * 1000;

    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

requestAnimationFrame(main);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#game {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
}
 <canvas id="game"></canvas>




You're right, it is a little more pleasant to look at. Is it common to set 60 FPS in pixel art games? According to certain documentation and forums, the unwritten standard is 24FPS. However, there is still the problem that the background is blurred due to the normalization of the diagonal vector. Is there any approach here?
